# aws GLUE java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space # -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark

I know this has been asked before, but unfortunately my problem is of a different nature.

I'm trying to convert a 150gb txt file in to parquet. I have a simple standard script for this in Glue. But somehow it keeps throwing mee a java heap space error " *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space # -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9*".

4 things i have tried 
-I tried repartitioning on the dynamicFrame

- I have tweaked spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=xxxx
- I have tweaked spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=xxxx
- change dpu amount

But no luck

Another problem i run in to is that the section in the GLue console where i can specify the job parameters, i can only provide 1 spark conf, when i provide multiple spark configs, only the first one is accepted.

So how can i make sure my extremely simple spark job runs without heap space errors?

Comment: Facing the same issue.

Comment: How was this resolved?

Comment: finally! https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/aws-glue-now-supports-additional-configuration-options-for-memory-intensive-jobs/

Comment: Waiting to try this out . Will update the thread soon.